# Issue with Search in Community (Napili)

Tags: customer-community, napili

I'm having a bit of trouble with the Search page in a Community. I've got Knowledge activated and articles published. When I search one by name, they pop up in the search box:

[image]

I can click on the article there and view it correctly. But when I click on search and follow through to the Search page, there are no results.

[image]

Does anyone know why this might be happening? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

As you can see, the searchbar is suggesting articles and questions. However,  the search component of the search page needs to be configured in order to display the object types you want. if you click on it in builder mode, you should be able to select and see what objects are returned in the search.

[image]